# How can a dynamically generated Drupal menu be converted into a static one?

Tags: drupal, dynamic, menu

Is there a way to convert dynamically generated menu's into static one, to make them available to modules that enhance the menus?

e.g. the Book Navigation block generates a menu, but if you want to enhance it with  `Superfish` or `Nice Menus`, it doesn't show up in the list of menus.

Here is another example -

```
<?php
  $book_top_page= YOUR_NID;
  $tree = menu_tree_all_data(book_menu_name($book_top_page));
  print drupal_render(menu_tree_output($tree));
?>
```

This code generates a menu, but it can't be added to the standard menus automatically. Is there a way to generate a proper editor menu from the generated code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're specifically talking about nice_menus then you can just pass the menu into theme_nice_menu to generate the output you need.

Here's [a D6 example](http://drupal.org/node/236418#comment-1024401):

```
<?php
  $menu = theme('nice_menu', 1, 'book-toc-1', NULL, 'down');
  print $menu['content'];
?>
```

I would expect superfish to have a similar theme function and I would also expect the syntax to be almost identical for D7 if that's what you're using.

Comment: In the above example what would be the parameter passed to theme('nice_menu', etc). Can either menu_tree_all_data or menu_tree_output be passed to the theme function?